# What is the best to use: str_replace, no str_replace or any other option?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, str-replace

What is the best to use: str_replace, no str_replace or any other option?

For example I have an array that is not empty and is generated by php based on a XML file, I have a variable that is in need of a change. if value is in the array and the variable has a standard value, the value should be changed to an other value (translation, other word(s) etc).

I can do this with the code below:

```
<?php
$ethnic_later = 'niet opgegeven';
$ethnic_array = array(  'Blank',
                        'getint',
                        'Aziatisch',
                        'Zuid-Amerikaans'
                    );
if (in_array('Blank', $ethnic_array) && $ethnic == 'Blank'){
    $ethnic = str_replace($ethnic, 'blanke', $ethnic);
}elseif (in_array('getint', $ethnic_array) && $ethnic == 'getint'){
    $ethnic = str_replace($ethnic, 'getinte', $ethnic);
}elseif (in_array('Aziatisch', $ethnic_array) && $ethnic == 'Aziatisch'){
    $ethnic = str_replace($ethnic, 'Aziatische', $ethnic);
}elseif(in_array($ethnic, $ethnic_array) && $ethnic == 'Zuid-Amerikaans'){
    $ethnic = str_replace($ethnic, 'Zuid Amerikaanse', $ethnic);
}else{
    $ethnic = str_replace($ethnic, $ethnic_later, $ethnic);
}

echo 'een mooie ' . $ethnic . ' kleur';
?>
```

Or I can just overwrite the value of `$ethnic` without using the php function `str_replace()` like below:

```
<?php
$ethnic_later = 'niet opgegeven';
$ethnic_array = array(  'Blank',
                        'getint',
                        'Aziatisch',
                        'Zuid-Amerikaans'
                    );
if (in_array('Blank', $ethnic_array) && $ethnic == 'Blank'){
    $ethnic = 'blanke';
}elseif (in_array('getint', $ethnic_array) && $ethnic == 'getint'){
    $ethnic = 'getinte';
}elseif (in_array('Aziatisch', $ethnic_array) && $ethnic == 'Aziatisch'){
    $ethnic = 'Aziatische';
}elseif(in_array($ethnic, $ethnic_array) && $ethnic == 'Zuid-Amerikaans'){
    $ethnic = 'Zuid Amerikaanse';
}else{
    $ethnic = $ethnic_later;
}

echo 'een mooie ' . $ethnic . ' kleur';
?>
```

There are more possibilities to get something like this to work, I posted 2 above... I believe the last option without using `str_replace()` is faster than using `str_replace()`...

> My question: What is the best way to do what I want using `PHP` and how do you do this kind of tasks?

Comment: `'White', 'Black', 'Yellow'` ftfy

Comment: @user2176127 yes, that's the other way to create an array,  it's not more readable but is `array('White', 'Black', 'Yellow');` faster?

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that is indexed by the values you expect in $ethnic, and contains the strings you would like the $ethnic variables to map to, like so:

```
<?php
$ethnic_later = 'niet opgegeven';
$ethnic_array = array(  'Blank' => 'blanke',
                'getint' => 'getinte',
                'Aziatisch' => 'Aziatische',
                'Zuid-Amerikaans' => 'Zuid Amerikaanse'
                );  
if (isset($ethnic_array[$ethnic])) {
        $ethnic = $ethnic_array[$ethnic];
}else{
        $ethnic = $ethnic_later;
}

echo 'een mooie ' . $ethnic . ' kleur';
```

When you want to add more $ethnics, add more elements to the array.

Comment: Thank you for your input, code is way shorter and may be it's faster as well I didn't test the speed,.,